# Showing "gaps" in ordinal time-based data in Vega-Lite

Tags: charts, vega-lite, vega

When charting data In Vega-Lite with a time-based x-axis, [it's common to use an "ordinal" type scale](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/timeunit.html#time-unit-with-ordinal-fields), which causes Vega-Lite to behave in nice ways for certain chart types. [Here's an example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOcNZkFx+AdxP042ylAjEQAXyXJtAa31Mk2xSBwslBsyjSyZGigAB5RIJg0CHAAqrJ0+ghy9AEAZjRwgsr6qphwAZgAnjhl6GzaYbJIem4gFXFIZGTafKUZJvJKeQVF6DjdUDQ4dGrs8i7zQA):

[image: time chart with ordinal scale]

However, this has an unfortunate side-effect - "gaps" in the data where no values are present for a certain time period disappear on the chart ([example](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOcNZkFx+AdxP042ylAjEQAXyXJtAa31Mk2xSCY2kiyEABmbNoIaADaoGE0gph2+ghy9AAUqpgMCJTZcACUAAQAhAC8xQDMrgC6SnCyUGzKNLJkaKAAHp2BNAhwAKqydKnpMAEJcILK+gUBmACeOHD6ka2ySHpuIIu9SGRk2nzJqSbySlMz+jjHUDQ4dGrs8i5vQA)). This can be fixed by switching the type to `temporal`, but this has other effects that make it not usable (like changing the default axis labeling and not being able to use x-offset to make grouped bar charts). Notice in the demo below, how May follows directly after March when using `ordinal`:

[image: switching between temporal and ordinal]

What is the best way to deal with this? More precisely, how can we get a time-based chart using `ordinal` to display labels and empty columns for "gaps" in the time-based data (regardless of what the specific `timeUnit` being used is)?

---

**Edit**: in response to comments about why `temporal` doesn't work:

Here's [an ordinal chart where Q2 is missing](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOcNZkFx+AdxP042ylAjEQAXyXJtAazShMATxw4fSYkbVclTG0kWQgAMzZtBDQAbVBYmkFMO30ARwZQrO0AClVMBgRKUrgASgACAEIAXlqAJlcAXSU4WSg2ZRpZMh8QAA9hzBoEOABVWTpc-O1CxRB0uEFlfSqV-0D9BP7ZJD0IunN9AFk5elq2WNrbWr8TMKUQ2WUABTYIOnZ5VAABjcID8wyQZDI2j4WX0vQYskwOwCQXQeWiE3UE1I4RAvUECWGaw2+msangYRBIwA8rFYhA4EjNKsaOtNugybZKS4XEA). I'd like there to be an empty, labeled section for Q2 instead of it just being omitted.

[image]

[Here's the same chart using `temporal`](https://vega.github.io/editor/#/url/vega-lite/N4IgJAzgxgFgpgWwIYgFwhgF0wBwqgegIDc4BzJAOjIEtMYBXAI0poHsDp5kTykBaADZ04JAKyUAVhDYA7EABoQAEySYUqUAwBOgtCrVJOcNZkFx+AdxP042ylAjEQAXyXJtAazShMATxw4fSYkbVclTG0kWQgAMzZtBDQAbVBYmkFMO30ARwZQrO0AClVMBgRKUrgASgACAEIAXlqAJlcAXSU4WSg2ZRpZMh8QAA9hzBoEOABVWTpc-O1CxRB0uEFlfSqV-0D9LIQcBKQ9CLpzfQBZOXpatlja21q-EzClENllAAU2CDp2eSoAAMbhAfmGSDIZG0fCy+l6DFkmB2ASC6Dy0Qm6gmpHCIF6ggSwzWG301jU8DCoJGAHlYrEIHBkZpVjR1pt0OTbFSXC4gA). It has the desired empty section, but other negative qualities. Note how the default labeling system is wonkier with some labels repeated. Also note how `xOffset` no longer works and it's no longer possible to make a chart with side-by-side bars.

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do as I don't understand. Clearly state your desired end result and provide a sample spec if you can. I don't get the problem with using temporal?

Comment: Also, are you limited to Vega-Lite or can you also use Vega?

Comment: @David, I added some more explanation above on why `temporal` won't work, does that help? I can only use Vega-Lite in this case.

Comment: I see what you mean now. This looks like it is not currently supported. I'll raise the issue here: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7722

Answer (score 1):

In the meantime, you can try setting a custom domain like this.

[image]

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega-lite/v5.json",
  "data": {"url": "data/seattle-weather.csv"},
  "mark": {"type": "bar"},
  "transform": [{"filter": "quarter(datum.date) != 2"}],
  "encoding": {
    "x": {
      "timeUnit": "quarter",
      "field": "date",
      "type": "ordinal",
      "title": "Quarter of the year",
      "bandPosition": 0,
      "scale": {
        "domain": [{"quarter": 1},{"quarter": 2},{"quarter": 3},{"quarter": 4}]
      }
    },
    "y": {"aggregate": "count", "type": "quantitative"},
    "color": {"field": "weather"},
    "xOffset": {"field": "weather"}
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the best workaround for now. There are some unfortunate parts still - for example, if we used a `yearquarter` time unit, we'd have to introspect the data to see what "gaps" exist and programmatically generate the domain? But for time units like `month` or `quarter` which have a constant domain this seems like it works well!